# Populating Table View with content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, tableview

I am new to iphone app development.

I currently have a table view but want to populate it with my own news stories any idea how I could go about this?

Currently I have the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "premier-league")
        cell.postTitleLabel.text = "Join our league"
        cell.authorLabel.text = "Paul"
        cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "author")

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "example2")
        cell.postTitleLabel.text = "Fixtures for the coming season"
        cell.authorLabel.text = "Paul"
        cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "author")

    } else {
        cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "example3")
        cell.postTitleLabel.text = "New App for the new season"
        cell.authorLabel.text = "Paul"
        cell.authorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "author")

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain very well. I want to populate the table with an rss feed from wordpress to include my image in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the thing you need to understand is the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have shown above, is the method which is repeatedly called that populates the cells of a tableView - that's all there is to it.

Thus if you had the following implementation:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = "Hello"
    return cell
}
```

Then every cell's `textLabel` would be populated with the word "hello".

Expanding on this all you need to do, is populate an array (or other object) with the data you want to display in the tableView (i.e. an array of String names, Dates, some other data) and then set a property (textLabel or other) of the cell with that data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The best bit is, each indexPath.row is a perfect analog for each array position. So arrays and tableViews go hand in hand nicely.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not recursively called. Perhaps you meant "repeatedly called?"

Comment: @ndmeiri yes! Sorry :)

Comment: No problem! Just want to hopefully avoid any confusion for a future reader who happens to peruse your thorough answer :)