# Save text in array and display in a table view

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to create an app that displays a table view based on an array of strings.

I have one view controller and a smaller content view within it. In the view controller there is a text field and a button that should save the written text in an array and display it in the table view controller. As well as embedding it in the content view.

I don't know how to save the written text and to add it in the array, perhaps using append.

How can I display the array in the table view and to save the array in NSUserDefaults?

EDIT:
Here's an image of the view controller and the content view. I want to insert one string in the text field (the one over the green button Save), then I tap the green button and the string I wrote is added in the array and displayed in a table view cell of the table view controller embed in the content view. At the same time, the text field return empty, but I already know how to clear it. Then, I can re-write texts in the text field and it should repeats the actions I just described.
A the moment isn't so important to save in NSUserDefaults.
Thanks for the help. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5uTc.png

EDIT 2:

MainVC

```
import UIKit

class mainVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!
var embTableVC: tableVC!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "embededTableVC" {
        embTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! tableVC
    }
}

@IBAction func Save() {
    if let Text = txtField.text {
        if txtField.text == "" {
            myArray.append(Text)
            let row = myArray.count-1
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
            embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
 txtField.text = ""
    txtField.resignFirstResponder()
}     
}
```

TableVC

```
  import UIKit

  var myArray = [String]()

  class tableVC: UITableViewController {
  @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customcell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you give more details on exactly what you want to happen in what order? And also perhaps a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: See the edit, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To store the information:

```js
// Get the standardUserDefaults object, store your UITableView data array against a key, synchronize the defaults
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfImage forKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
[userDefaults setObject:arrayOfText forKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve the information:

```js
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataImage"];
NSArray *arrayOfText = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataText"];
// Use 'yourArray' to repopulate your UITableView
On first load, check whether the result that comes back from NSUserDefaults is nil, if it is, you need to create your data, otherwise load the data from NSUserDefaults and your UITableView will maintain state.
```

In Swift, the following approach can be used:

```js
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(arrayOfImage, forKey:"tableViewDataImage")
userDefaults.setObject(setObject:arrayOfText, forKey:"tableViewDataText")
userDefaults.synchronize()

var arrayOfImages = userDefaults.objectForKey("tableViewDataImage")
var arrayOfText = userDefaults.objectForKey("tableViewDataText")
```

Hope this helps. You can also use a xcdatamodeld to save and retrieve data.

Comment: Thanks, don't you know how to save text in array from textfield?:)

Comment: You should be able to do something like this to send it to an array. Just add this to viewDidLoad: method and it should work fine: textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for storing the text in an array, a better option than NSUserDefaults if you might have a large number of Strings.

First, you will need to have an Array of Strings in the View Controller managing the Table View. Then, you will need a way to access that Array and edit it.

I would store a reference to the table view controller within the first view controller (with the container). To first set this reference, use the embed segue.

In your storyboard, the arrow connecting the first VC to the table VC is actually an embed segue that fires upon load of the container view. Click the segue, and in the attributes inspector in Xcode change the identifier to some String such as "embedTableVC".

Then we can set the reference in the first view controller. Here's some relevant code, assuming the view controller with the container has a class of MainViewController and the table view controller within the container has a class of TableViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var embededTableVC: TableViewController!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "embedTableVC" {
            embededTableVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
        }
    }

}
```

Once the main view controller loads, the container will be loaded, which will then cause the segue to run, which will cause prepareForSegue to be called. In this implementation, we are storing the table view controller in a property on our main view controller so we can access it. Since classes are reference types, this property will refer to the same object, not a copy.

Then, you get the text from the text field once the save button is pressed, and set it to the array in the table VC, like this:

```
@IBAction func save() {
    if let text = textField.text {
        if text != "" {
            embededTableVC.valueArray.append(text)
            // and if you want to go ahead and add it to the array from here instead of using delegation or notification observance
            let row = embededTableVC.valueArray.count - 1
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}
```

The if-let syntax ensures the text property of the text field is not nil.

I believe this is what you were looking for, but keep in mind that everything will be gone upon app relaunch, since we're not using NSUserDefaults or Core Data to store anything to the device's drive. You'll want a combination of the two approaches if you need persistence.

**Edit:**
As far as populating the table view with content from the array, you should consult [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5), as explaining it here would get pretty lengthy and the information may be found easily. Alternatively, you can check out [this article](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/) to get an understanding for populating the table view, or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037237/populating-table-view-with-content). You will need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at a minimum for your table view.

**Edit 2:**
After reading your code, I'd say there are many things that probably ought to be changed eventually, but just to get it to work for now, the following changes need made for now:

Change this (from `Save()`)…

```
if let Text = txtField.text {
    if txtField.text == "" {
        myArray.append(Text)
        let row = myArray.count-1
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
        embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

…to this

```
if let text = txtField?.text {
    if text != "" { // Notice the two changes on this line
        myArray.append(text)
        let row = myArray.count - 1
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
        embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

Change this (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)…

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

…to this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row] // Notice `row`, not item`

    return cell
}
```

If you're still getting a crash because a nil optional was unwrapped, which is highly possible, I need to know what line Xcode crashes on and I need to know what the error says.

Comment: I have some problems: in the declaration of the var embededTableVC: TableViewController! I have to write UITableViewController! instead of TableViewController (I don't know why). Then, in the override func prepareForSegue the word override says "Method does not override any method from its superclass". In the IBAction func save in the line embededTableVC.valueArray.append(text) the word valueArray says "Value of type UITableViewController has no member valueArray". Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: The sample code I provided will need modified depending on your setup. "TableViewController" represents whatever you named the custom class of the UITableViewController. "MainViewController" represents whatever you call your custom class for the view controller holding the container and button. "override func prepareForSegue" should be placed inside the brackets of the view controller holding the container, not on its own. "valueArray" represents what you call the Array on the custom class representing your table view controller. Ensure IBAction and custom classes are specified in storyboard.

Comment: I tried the advices you gave me but I still have some problems. The override func prepareForSegue doesn't work and says "Method does not override any method from its superclass". If I delete "override", the issue disappear. With the embededTableVC.valueArray.append(text) it says me "Value of type UITableViewController has no member valueArray. The other problems you said me how to solve them, are now solved, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a custom class for the table view controller? You should, and this is where you would create a String array that would be referenced in the main VC by whatever you called it, "valueArray" in the example. If "prepareForSegue" is really inside the main VC custom class that is a subclass of UIViewController (which is where it needs to be), it should require the override keyword. If necessary, I will create a very simple example Xcode project to show you the setup.

Comment: Yes, I have a custom class for the table view controller. Here I declared var myArray = [String](). I solved the override func problem. I tried to compile but when I write my string in the textField, the table view doesn't show anything

Comment: Okay, as long as you have made sure 'myArray' is indeed being updated, and that you have programmed the tableView to display the results of the array, you are on the right track. You still need to update the UI when the contents of the Array change. You could either use more advanced communication -- http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/ -- or simply call `embededTableVC.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths` at the end of your save() function, causing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called, pulling the data from the array you updated.

Comment: Ok, now I think I'm almost at the end. What have I to write in the brackets at the end of embededTableVC.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths? And where do I use cellForRowAtIndexPath? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I edited my answer. It sounds like you may not already have code in your table view controller to populate the cells based on the array. Refer to the resources provided in the edit. Thanks

Comment: I didn't get what you mean in the edit. In the class that controls the table view I already wrote the numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath functions. In the first function the return = 0, in the second is array.count and in the third I wrote: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell - let row = indexPath.row - cell.textLabel?.text = array[row] return cell. In the save function I wrote embededTableVC.myTableView.inserRowsAtIndexing() but I don't know what have I to write in the brackets.

Comment: Sorry, I added that info just now to the save() code snippet. Hope that does it for you. :)

Comment: Is valueArray the name of the array I use in the code? Because the code is crashing. When I tap on the save button the console says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" thanks :)

Comment: "valueArray" is whatever you called the array in the Table VC.  I believe you called it myArray.

Comment: Ok, I called it myArray, but the app continues crashing

Comment: If you don't mind posting your code in an edit to your answer, that would be best. That way others can be helped by it as well.

Comment: Well, tomorrow I post the code as an edit of my question. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. The problems I found in your code are probably not what was causing the crash, but they still need to be fixed. If the crash continues, let me know what line Xcode highlights with the error and the error message.

Comment: With the code you wrote I can compile and run the app on the device, but when I tap the save button I become this in the console: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Thanks a lot for the patience :)

Comment: And on which line did it find nil? It should be highlighted in green.

Comment: I can't see it. It just says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value ":/

Comment: When the app crashes in the simulator, Xcode should highlight a line in green telling you where the crash took place. If that line is not a line you wrote, then you can change the code you're looking at by choosing a new entry in the sidebar that automatically shows up after a crash and a new line should be highlighted. Without knowing where it's crashing, it's going to be guess-and-check.

Comment: Just looking at the code that's being called when you hit save, I only see one optional being unwrapped, and it's being unwrapped safely if you copied the code I had in the second edit. I just added one `?` after `txtField`. You can try that, but if that's really what was causing it, it sounds like your txtField variable is not being properly initialized.

Comment: The line is "embTableVC.myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)"

Comment: Okay, so there are two things on that line that could theoretically be nil: embTableVC and myTableView. Right before that line, put two print statements: `print(embTableVC?)` and `print(embTableVC?.myTableView?)`. That way, right before the crash, you can see which of those printed nil. Be sure to keep the question marks in the print statements

Comment: Nothing happens :/ continues crashing and nothing is printed

Comment: And now what line is highlighted red?

Comment: Hmm…try changing `inSection` in the NSIndexPath creation to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Always the same line is highlighted in green. I tried changing 1 to 0 but nothing to do

Comment: I want you to get this taken care of, but I'm not sure how much more I can help you. Since this is a much narrower problem than you originally asked, you should probably post a new question with your code and dilemma and stating which line the error is on. That way others can look at it. If those print statement were placed before the line with the problem and with the question marks, they should have printed something as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yep, sorry I couldn't be more of a help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {      

**var message = ["a","b"]
var toPass: String!**

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        **message.append(toPass)**           
    }    

@IBAction func SendButon(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue2", sender: nil)
}      

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   // tableView.reloadData()
    return message.count
}    

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                       forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellFor")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellFor", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.labelView.text = message[indexPath.row]

        return cell       
    }           
}
```